# Cycle Notation Calculations of S6

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, symmetric-groups, cyclic-groups

I particularly need help on i and iii

The general question that I have is to:

Perform the following calculations of elements of S6 in cycle notation:

i) ((156)(234))^-1

ii) (134).(12)(45)

iii) (12)(45).(134)

iv) (123)(45).(45)

v) (1234)^(15)(24)(36)

vi) (12)(34).(13)(24).(14)(23)

i) ((156)(234))^-1 = (156)^-1 (234)^-1 = (651)(432)

ii) (134).(12)(45) **What does the dot mean does it have a different effect to having no dots as the second brackets do.**

Anyway I have (51234).

iii) I have this as (135) I am unsure if this is correct?

iv) I have (123)(4)(5) reducing to (123) I am fairly sure this is correct.

v) Applying A^B = B^-1 AB = (3)(6254) which reduces to (6254).

vi) Is fairly simple - (2)(3)(1)(4) reduces to e.

Any help would be so appreciated thnx

Comment: I've never seen dots used in cycle notation. This may be specific to your text or a simple typographical error. I would check your text.

Comment: @SeanRoberson thnx for the response and the edit. Hmmn okay I also had never seen this before these are excerpts taken from my mock papers. I have always assumed that they are no different to having no dots. This is notation used by my teacher who is sadly unavailable :L

Comment: It looks like the dot is being used in this way: One element is $(134)$, another element is $(12)(45)$, and you're being asked to find their product.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs thank you for your response, are you saying that I should first consider the two elements individually, applying cycle notation if neccesary and then as you said - find thier product?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "first consider the two elements individually". I'm also not sure how notation works in your book, as far as reading these things from left-to-right or from right-to-left. In number (ii), which is meant to happen first, $(134)$ or $(12)(45)$?

Comment: (12)(45) the elements to the right thanks for the assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i) ii) I have the same results

iii) I have $(13542)$

iv) yes, first two cycles are inverses, and cancel each other out.

v) $(1234)^{(15)} = (15)(1234)(15) = (5234)\\
(5234)(24)(36) = (25)(36)$

if it is supposed to be:

$(1234)^{(15)(24)(36)} = (15)(24)(36)(1234)(15)(24)(36)$

I think of conjugation as a change of bases.  I doesn't change the structure of the cycles.  It does change the way elements map in a rather straight forward way.  $(5462)$

vi) $(12)(34),(13)(24),$ and $(14)(23)$ generate a group isomorphic to the $K_4$ group.  Their product equals the identity.

Comment: I see now how you calculated iii thanks for that, I can see I was almost there. It was the latter for what you did for part v). Really thank you a lot for your help. I can see I almost had them all right. Sir, could I just check with you for vi) is it acceptable to leave the final answer as e, where e is the identity. Kind Regards

Comment: you could say $e$ you could also say $()$ for the identity.  Or you could say $(1)(2)(3)(4)$

Comment: ah yes this is familiar thank you again.